# How to find Max value of second element of std::pair in std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I have vector of pairs in this order {{label, probability},{label, probability}}. I want to get the pair which has the maximum value of probability. Here's my attempt to accomplish that, but instead of getting the max value of probability, it returns the max value of the label string. e.g. label dog is the largest value because of alphabet order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, float>> pairs;
    pairs = {{"apple",34.785}, {"banana",67.8467}, {"dog", 13.476}, {"cat",56.486}};

    const auto p = max_element(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());
    auto label = p->first;
    auto prob = p->second;

    std::cout<<label<<" "<<prob;
}
```

Output : `dog 13.476`

Comment: Just pass the comparison lambda as the third argument to the `max_element` method, i.e.:`[](const auto &a, const auto &b) { return a.second < b.second; }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide a customized comparator to `max_element`, e.g.

```
max_element(pairs.begin(), 
            pairs.end(), 
            [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs.second < rhs.second; });
```

Otherwise, [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) will use the [`operator<` of `std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) as the comparator, which will check both the two elements of `std::pair`.

Note : works on C++14 and higher

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KfeMIa08TTJSeahm)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that I have to put customized comparator. Btw, 1 edit, it will only work on C++ 14 and higher

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by custom comparator function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool compare(std::pair<std::string, float> p1, std::pair<std::string, float> p2) {
    return p1.second<p2.second;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, float>> pairs;
    pairs = {{"apple",34.785}, {"banana",67.8467}, {"dog", 13.476}, {"cat",56.486}};

    const auto p = max_element(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), compare);
    auto label = p->first;
    auto prob = p->second;

    std::cout<<label<<" "<<prob;
}
```